# Recommended plot type

Tags: plotly, plotly.js, plotly-python

I have a data for which i want to have a line chart and for the same data i want to have a plot which can show me things in degrees when i hover the line chart. In degree chart, i want to have 2 to 3 outer axis or layers . I have created a ugly looking sample chart in excel like below
[image]

Is this possible in plotly? which plot type i should use to get this . I have a line chart for this, i want to know whether this type of data visualisation is possible in plotly. Thank you

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: Looks to me like a custom polar chart... https://plot.ly/python/polar-chart/. Maybe you can use them to create your own chart.